# Ubuntu - 4 physical nics, same subnet? Not load-balancing

Tags: networking, ubuntu, network-adapter

I've looked at a lot of the answers related to this topic, but most are discussing load balancing or bonding for redundancy.  My issue is a lot simpler.

I have an industrial PC with 4 POE nics that connects to 4 cameras.  The cameras all have static IPs on 192.168.1.x/24.  Today they are all connected to a POE switch, so it's not an issue.  But, the new device handles everything in one - no more need for a switch.

Is there a way to put these 4 NICs on the same subnet?  There is no gateway, they don't need to route - the PC just needs to reach the static IP of the cameras, nothing else.

I'd have to have to make 4 different sub-nets if I could avoid it.

Thanks.

Comment: The absolute simplest is just to put each NIC of the PC in its own 4-number subnet.  (you cannot make do with 2 as you need the broadcast address too), and reassign each camera to such an address.    I think you should reconsider doing that.

Answer (score 2):

Put all four NICs in a "bridge" interface. You can create one through Netplan or systemd-networkd or /etc/network/interfaces (or whatever your version of Ubuntu uses), but the "manual" setup looks like:

```
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up

ip addr flush eth0 scope global
ip addr flush eth1 scope global
...

ip link set eth0 master br0
ip link set eth1 master br0
...

ip addr add 192.168.1.1/24 dev br0
```

Note that *only* the bridge interface needs to have an IP address (it represents the host's own connection to the bridge) but not the individual port interfaces.